# How optimize background video on the web page in Chrome browser?

Tags: html, performance, google-chrome, video, optimization

Now we are upgrading the landing page on our web site with a new popular design - with a video in the background, like here https://globalid.net/. But I've found that after 30-60 seconds of page preview, my laptop becomes so hot and system manager shows me that Chrome is getting about 50% CPU but it really does nothing, it's a plain one page with a small 30 seconds video fragment ~4.5 MB.

So, could anybody explain how to solve this problem? Why Chrome is so greedy for resources?

Thanks!

P.S.

After exploring other sites with the video on the landing page, i've found that all of them make system slow (30-100% CPU)
E.x.:

https://smartslider3.com/yoga-hero-block/ 
Video size 1.5 MB, 15 sec, 24 frame/s, 1920*1081
30-60% CPU

https://theenglishbus.com/ 
70-100% CPU

It seems it doesn't matter the size of the video, for Chrome it just endless "HD movie".

Comment: does the video cause the same CPU load if just displayed normally in a web page (ie with nothing in front of it) ... the problem may be that the elements stacked on top of it are requiring more compute to resolve.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't depend on elements, but on endless video stream. I've added extra examples in the description.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is disabling 'loop' in the promo video, and after that in some way to check if it's happened and then just to show the slides.